# Line drawn over GridPane won't show

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I need a line separator in a `GridPane`. Not all lines visible, but rather one single in the middle. The way I'm currently doing it is putting in a `Pane` with a `Line` that overlays the `GridPane`:

```
StackPane secondSlide = new StackPane();
GridPane secondSlideCore = new GridPane();
// secondSlideCore is being filled with TextFields
secondSlide.getChildren().add(secondSlideCore);
Pane secondSlideOverlay = new Pane();

secondSlideOverlay.setPrefSize(secondSlideCore.getPrefWidth(), secondSlideCore.getPrefHeight());
Line mainOverlay = new Line(secondSlideOverlay.getPrefWidth() / 2, 0, secondSlideOverlay.getPrefWidth() / 2, secondSlideOverlay.getPrefHeight());
```

Later on I piece everything together:

```
secondSlideOverlay.getChildren().add(mainOverlay);
secondSlide.getChildren().add(secondSlideOverlay);
```

Even though `secondSlide` is being correctly added to the window (`secondSlideCore` does show), the line won't appear for some reason.

I tried all of the following to make it show:

```
mainOverlay.setFill(Color.BLACK);
mainOverlay.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
mainOverlay.setStrokeWidth(2);
mainOverlay.setVisible(true);
mainOverlay.setOpacity(1);
secondSlideOverlay.setVisible(true);
```

Still no line over my `GridPane`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prefWidth` and `prefHeight` default to the constant `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` which has the value of `-1.0`. For this reason you get more of a dot than a line (`(-0.5, 0)` to `(-0.5, -1)`).

Furthermore resizing the pane won't keep the line up to date.

Use bindings to fix this:

```
Pane secondSlideOverlay = new Pane();

secondSlideOverlay.prefWidthProperty().bind(secondSlideCore.widthProperty());
secondSlideOverlay.prefHeightProperty().bind(secondSlideCore.heightProperty());

DoubleExpression w2 = secondSlideCore.widthProperty().multiply(.5);

Line mainOverlay = new Line();
mainOverlay.startXProperty().bind(w2);
mainOverlay.endXProperty().bind(w2);
mainOverlay.endYProperty().bind(secondSlideCore.heightProperty());
```